# Prevent disconnections caused by intermittent packet loss

Tags: unity-networking, unity-game-engine

Been trying to find the issue here (Unity devs make it seem it's a design choice somehow), but I've been trying to simulate lag to see how my game works over the internet (I've also tried connecting a client from a tethered hotspot and it disconnected as well) and found that any amount of packet loss (even just 1%) will eventually lead to a disconnection within a couple minutes.

My game receives data just fine, as you can see the remote players moving around just fine until the disconnection. I think it has something to do with UNET's heartbeat packets not being resent for some reason, and has soon as it drops the first one you get disconnected.

If this is a design choice, I can't see how Unity would think you could have a rock solid connection when you obviously have some who could be playing off a cellular connection. Anyone know anything about this? I've tried asking on the Unity forums as well, and there's been no replies for over a week now.

Thanks